# Nuget Package Manager for single project fails to load after adding RingCentralSDK

Tags: nuget, ringcentral

I'm on VS 2015, targeting .net 4.5.2, my "Nuget Package Manager for Visual Studio" in Extensions and Updates shows 3.4.4.1321.

I added all dependencies of RingCentralSDK package separately:

- Microsoft.Bcl
- Microsoft.Bcl.Async
- Microsoft.Bcl.Build
- Microsoft.Net.Http
- Newtonsoft.Json
- Portable.BouncyCastle-Signed
- PubnubPCL

Then I right click on my project, pick "Manage Nuget Packages...", the tab opens, in the "Installed" subtab I can see the 7 packages.

Now, I install the RingCentralSDK package. My output is fine:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0' with respect to project 'MyProj', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0'
Adding package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\code\packages'
Added package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\code\packages'
Added package 'RingCentralSDK.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'RingCentralSDK 1.0.0' to MyProj
========== Finished ==========
```

Now, I check again the Manage Nuget Packages for this specific project, and instead of seeing the list of packages, I get a yellow band:

```
Error occured                  Show erros in output         Dismiss
```

And in the "Package Manager" output, the error is:

```
ZIP archive contains unsupported data structures.
```

In my packages folder, the folder "RingCentralSDK.1.0.0" seems ok, but then I don't anything about nuget packages format.

I cannot uninstall RingCentral via the package manager as it's not showing, not any other one, which is really annoying. I had an error when trying to do it via the command line. I reverted my changes (or remove the line in packages.config for my project), and the Nuget Package Manager tab works fine again. This is also affecting the "Managet Nuget Packages for Solution".

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in `RingCentralSDK 1.0.1-alpha1`

It turns out that the NuGet package created on Mac is not compatible with Visual Studio NuGet GUI tool.

You can install the latest version by

`Install-Package RingCentralSDK -Pre`

Or if you prefer GUI:

[image]

**Update:**

For projects which already have `1.0.0` version installed, how to upgrade?

Today I did some testing and I came to the following conclusion:

1. New project will have no problem with 1.0.1 version or later
2. For old project which have 1.0.0 installed. You need to follow the following steps:

   1. UnInstall RingCentralSDK 1.0.0
   2. Close VS
   3. Delete packages folder in your project
   4. Delete packages folder in ~/.nuget/
   5. Launch VS
   6. Install RingCentralSDK 1.0.1

I need to do the above because nuget has cache. If I don't do it the problem just persists. I don't know the exactly reason but the above steps did work for me.

Comment: Failed at first, but it works now: I had to remove the old ref, close VS, delete 1.0.0 and 1.0.1alpha folders from packages folder, re-open VS, and finally readd the 1.0.1alpha reference. VS+Nuget = Flaky !